# Variable binding and keyword this in Java

Tags: java

In the following code how does the variable x in the method getX() get bound to the member field of instance of Class A even when at runtime 'this' refers to an object of type B. Does this happen at compile time or at run time.

```
class A {

    public void getX(){
        Class cls = this.getClass();  
        System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + cls.getName());
        System.out.format("value of x = %d\n", this.x);}

    public int x = 0;
}

public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        obj.getX();}

    public int x = 1;
}
```

the output  is:

```
The type of the object is: B
value of x = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Fields are not resolved polymorphically. At compile time, `this.x` is resolved statically to "get the value of the field x defined in class A".

Comment: Fields can be hidden by subclasses. Field `x` is not a static field, so the access is not static.

Comment: Yes, so what? They're hidden, and not overridden, which is precisely the reason 0 is displayed rather than 1. And I didn't say that the acces was static. I said that x wasn't resolved polymorphically, but statically.

Comment: Right answer. The `B.this` adds memory, so x stays at the same spot of the memory of `this`.

Comment: So if 'this.x' gets resolved at compile time then 'this' does not refer to the current object? Is it just ignored?

Comment: `this` does refer to the current object. The current object is of type A (in addition to being of type B), and A has a field called x. When this.foo() is resolved, it's resolved polymorphically, at runtime. So it looks for a method `foo()` in the *runtime* type of `this`, which is B, then in A, then in Object. But `this.x` is resolved at compile time. The compiler  looks for a field named x in the *declared* type of `this` (which is A), then in Object.

Comment: If that's what you mean, that's what you should say; don't invent new terminology and expect anyone to understand it. The term "resolved statically" does not appear in the Java Language Specification (or anywhere else in the Java documentation that I know of). Using the word "statically" in this context is, at best, meaningless and is quite likely confusing to someone trying to understand how Java works. What's going on here has nothing to do with Java concepts related to the keyword "static".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution. I didn't invent this terminology. "statically" means "not dynamically" in this context.

Comment: I am confused by the terminology. If we say that 'this' refers to the 'current object' then we should not be talking about terms like 'statically' or 'at compile time' since at that time there is no current object. That is why I thought the declared type of 'this' was B since this is what the declared type of obj is and that is what gets passed as the implicit parameter in the call obj.getX().

Comment: When the compiler compiles the instance method `getX()` in class A, `this` refers to the current object, and is of type A, since the method is part of class A. The compiler doesn't even know that there is a B subclass. So `this.x` is compiled to the byte-code instruction "read the value of the field x declared in A for the current object". And it's resolved at compile time. So if `x` was defined in a superclass Alpha of A, it would compile it to "read the value of the field x declared in Alpha for the current object".

Comment: Now suppose `getX()` calls a protected or public method `this.foo()`. The compiler would compile it to "invoke the method `foo()` on the current object, and look for such a method in the concrete runtime type of the current object, and go up the class hierarchy until you find such a method".

Comment: ok I think I have finally figured it out. At compile time `this` DOES NOT refer to the current object when used with variables because there isn't any but as the java language specification says: _The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs._. So the type of `this` in `getX()` above is the class A (@ JB Nizet mentioned this in his post when he said that the declared type of `this` is A). Since variables are bound statically at compile time the _declared type_ of `this` is used.

Comment: Additionally Java language Specification mentions that: _At run-time, the class of the actual object referred to may be the class C or any subclass of C_. So when `obj.getX()` is executed the actual class of `this` (the current object) is class B and only class B (I don't think that _current object is of type A (in addition to being of type B)_ as @JB Nizet mentions in his post is correct)

Comment: Congrats to finding the references in the JLS :-) The object's concrete type at runtime is of class B. And since B extends A, the object is also an instance of A. That's what I meant (although the JLS tells it better than me, obviously).